# Remove "/" from api call when optional parameter is null

Tags: java, jersey

We are using  **RESTful Web Services  (Jersey)** for API calls on java. While API needs optional parameter, we are doing as:

```
api-interface/user/userid/9000/companyid/90909/{optionalparameter*}
```

and we have to call this api when there is no optional parameter as:

```
api-interface/user/userid/9000/companyid/90909/
```

What needed is:

**Case:1 If optional parameter exists**

```
api-interface/user/userid/9000/companyid/90909/name/john/address/MA/age/34
```

**Case:2 If Optional parameter doesn't  exists.**

```
api-interface/user/userid/9000/companyid/90909
```

My present implementation is:

```
@GET
@Path("user/companyid/{companyid}/userid/{userid}/{optionalparameter:.*}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUserList(@PathParam("companyid") String companyId, @PathParam("userid") String userId,
            @PathParam("optionalparameter") String syncDate) throws BadRequestException, InternalServerException {
    //parsing the param.
  }
```

**In above code, I need to add trailing "/" but I am looking the way to remove this trailing "/" if anybody doesn't wants to pass those param.**

I followed this [link](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/15/jax-rs-path-pathparam-and-optional-parameters/) but it didn't worked while the preceding parameter's length is more then 1.

Please, Suggest me the best way.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? What happened when the parameter's length (do you mean number?) was more than one? What did Case:1 give you?

Comment: Yeah, While doing as this link i am able to remove that trailing "/" but it gave only one character for the required parameter (in above case, it gives companyId=9 but doesn't gives 90909) and remaining string after that first character becomes optional parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [your reference](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/15/jax-rs-path-pathparam-and-optional-parameters/), have you tried this:

```
@Path("userid/{userid}/companyid/{companyid}{optparam:(/[^/]+?)*}")
public Response getLocation(
        @PathParam("userid") int userid,
        @PathParam("companyid") int companyid,
        @PathParam("optparam") String optparam) {
    String[] params = parseParams(optparam);
    ...
}

private String[] parseParams(String params) {
    if (params.startsWith("/")) {
        params = path.substring(1);
    }
    return params.split("/");
}
```

That should work, giving you all the parameters in a single array.

**EDIT**: I have updated the search string and verified it on a local install.

Comment: How Jersey will detect the end of companyid and start of optional params?

Comment: I have already tried it and didn't worki am able to remove that trailing "/" but it gave only one character for the required parameter (in above case, it gives companyId=9 but doesn't gives 90909) and remaining string after that first character becomes optional parameter

Comment: @SanjayaPandey: I have updated my answer to fix the single character issue, and verified it on a local install.